# Disable ecdhe-cipher in IIS server

Tags: windows, security, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I would like to disable ecdhe cipher in IIS / windows 2008

I know how to list out all cipher is running , but how to disable it ?

Can anyone guide me in this ?

Answer (score 1):

The cipher suites are in your operating system, not in your web server. You can prioritize, add or delete cipher suites via regedit, but I highly recommend you to use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) for this. It'll allow you to perform all the previous actions, and it also includes a default configuration to remove all the insecure ciphers, like RC4, or insecure hash functions, like MD5.

But I'm curious about one thing, Why do you want to disable ECDHE? I mean, Elliptic Curve crypto is really awesome, since it allows you to work with short keys, providing the same level of security that you could get with much larger keys when using a different key exchange mechanism. I can't think of any good reason to disable it.